# Setting up network communication between R and Python

Tags: python, r

I want to share data between R and python via network sockets (I expect the solution to also work for R-R and python-python). I am interested in server being both R and Python side. For now I am interested in a simpler case of synchronous connections.

What are the best approaches, packages and formats to use for this task?

Comment: You should ask on StackOverflow since it is not related to Data Science !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) or [Protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) are common choices for serialization.

If you want to share data in-memory, there is the [Apache Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/) format which interoperates between many data types. If you want to share dataframes on disk, there is [Feather](https://github.com/wesm/feather).